# Get mifare card serial number with WinSCard library

Tags: c#, .net, rfid, mifare, winscard

I am working on an application that required reading the mifare card serial number, the language I am working with is C#.

I am new to mifare reader programming, so I am sorry for asking dumb question.
At first I would like to know if there is a different between Mifare UID and Mifare Serial number.

I have managed to get UID with the help of WinSCard library, but I cant figure it out how to get the card serial number which should be 10 digit numbers.

I do appreciate if you could point me to the right direction.

Thanks in advance for the help.
Regards

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**C# signature of SCardTransmit method**

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct SCARD_IO_REQUEST
{
   public int dwProtocol;
   public int cbPciLength;
}

[DllImport("winscard.dll")]
public static extern int SCardTransmit(int hCard, ref SCARD_IO_REQUEST pioSendRequest,    ref byte SendBuff, int SendBuffLen, ref SCARD_IO_REQUEST pioRecvRequest,
ref byte RecvBuff, ref int RecvBuffLen);
```

**Code Example for read UID of mifare card**

```
private SmartcardErrorCode GetUID(ref byte[] UID)
    {
        byte[] receivedUID = new byte[10];
        UnsafeNativeMethods.SCARD_IO_REQUEST request = new UnsafeNativeMethods.SCARD_IO_REQUEST();
        request.dwProtocol = 1; //SCARD_PROTOCOL_T1);
        request.cbPciLength =    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(UnsafeNativeMethods.SCARD_IO_REQUEST));
        byte[] sendBytes = new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xCA, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04 }; //get UID command      for Mifare cards

        int outBytes = receivedUID.Length;
        int status = SCardTransmit(_hCard, ref request, ref sendBytes[0], sendBytes.Length,  ref request, ref receivedUID[0], ref outBytes);

        UID = receivedUID.Take(8).ToArray(); 
        return status;
    }
```

Comment: the shown GetUID method is missing a cast of the returned status to the actual return type. It also has an unresolved reference to the _hCard variable.

Comment: Works after fixing a couple of issues: acording to https://github.com/amree/omnikey-mifare-samples-libraries/blob/master/Include/winsmcrd.h : SCARD_PROTOCOL_T1 = 2, changing the 1 to a 2 helped, used example at http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/winscard.scardestablishcontext to get _hCard (inserted above code just after <code>cardInserted = true;</code>)

Answer (score 3):

The Selected answer doesn't work on x64 enviroments.

Here is a Full example code, tested and working on Windows 10 x64.
What this does:

- Retrieve the List of Available Readers
- Selects to use the First available Reader
- Check if there is a Card in the reader and Connects to it.
- Transmits to the card the Command to retrieve its UID
- Converts the UID into a Hexadecimal string.

  ```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.ComponentModel;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
  using System.Text;

  namespace DXCutcsa.VO.Common
  {
      public class SmartCardReader
      {
          #region Atributos

      private bool _disposed = false;
      private IntPtr _ReaderContext = IntPtr.Zero;
      private string _ReaderName = string.Empty;
      private List<string> _AvailableReaders = new List<string>();

      #endregion

      #region Win32 APIs

      [DllImport("WinScard.dll")]
      static extern int SCardEstablishContext(uint dwScope,
          IntPtr notUsed1,
          IntPtr notUsed2,
          out IntPtr phContext);

      [DllImport("WinScard.dll")]
      static extern int SCardReleaseContext(IntPtr phContext);

      [DllImport("WinScard.dll")]
      static extern int SCardConnect(IntPtr hContext,
          string cReaderName,
          uint dwShareMode,
          uint dwPrefProtocol,
          ref IntPtr phCard,
          ref IntPtr ActiveProtocol);

      [DllImport("WinScard.dll")]
      static extern int SCardDisconnect(IntPtr hCard, int Disposition);

      [DllImport("WinScard.dll", EntryPoint = "SCardListReadersA", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
      static extern int SCardListReaders(
          IntPtr hContext,
          byte[] mszGroups,
          byte[] mszReaders,
          ref UInt32 pcchReaders);

      [DllImport("winscard.dll")]
      static extern int SCardStatus(
             uint hCard,
             IntPtr szReaderName,
             ref int pcchReaderLen,
             ref int pdwState,
             ref uint pdwProtocol,
             byte[] pbAtr,
             ref int pcbAtrLen);

      [DllImport("winscard.dll")]
      static extern int SCardTransmit(
          IntPtr hCard,
          ref SCARD_IO_REQUEST pioSendRequest,
          ref byte SendBuff,
          uint SendBuffLen,
          ref SCARD_IO_REQUEST pioRecvRequest,
          byte[] RecvBuff,
          ref uint RecvBuffLen);

      [DllImport("winscard.dll", SetLastError = true)]
      static extern int SCardGetAttrib(
         IntPtr hCard,            // Valor retornado en funcion ScardConnect
         UInt32 dwAttrId,         // Identificacion de atributos a obtener
         byte[] pbAttr,           // Puntero al vector atributos recividos 
         ref IntPtr pcbAttrLen    // Tamaño del vector
      );

      [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
      public struct ReaderState
      {
          public ReaderState(string sName)
          {
              this.szReader = sName;
              this.pvUserData = IntPtr.Zero;
              this.dwCurrentState = 0;
              this.dwEventState = 0;
              this.cbATR = 0;
              this.rgbATR = null;
          }

          internal string szReader;
          internal IntPtr pvUserData;
          internal uint dwCurrentState;
          internal uint dwEventState;
          internal uint cbATR;    // count of bytes in rgbATR
          [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 0x24, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.U1)]
          internal byte[] rgbATR;
      }

      [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
      public struct SCARD_IO_REQUEST
      {
          public UInt32 dwProtocol;
          public UInt32 cbPciLength;
      }


      /*****************************************************************/
      [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
      private extern static IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);

      [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
      private extern static void FreeLibrary(IntPtr handle);

      [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
      private extern static IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr handle, string procName);

      #endregion

      #region Error codes
      public const uint S_SUCCESS = 0x00000000;
      public const uint F_INTERNAL_ERROR = 0x80100001;
      public const uint E_CANCELLED = 0x80100002;
      public const uint E_INVALID_HANDLE = 0x80100003;
      public const uint E_INVALID_PARAMETER = 0x80100004;
      public const uint E_INVALID_TARGET = 0x80100005;
      public const uint E_NO_MEMORY = 0x80100006;
      public const uint F_WAITED_TOO_LONG = 0x80100007;
      public const uint E_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER = 0x80100008;
      public const uint E_UNKNOWN_READER = 0x80100009;
      public const uint E_TIMEOUT = 0x8010000A;
      public const uint E_SHARING_VIOLATION = 0x8010000B;
      public const uint E_NO_SMARTCARD = 0x8010000C;
      public const uint E_UNKNOWN_CARD = 0x8010000D;
      public const uint E_CANT_DISPOSE = 0x8010000E;
      public const uint E_PROTO_MISMATCH = 0x8010000F;
      public const uint E_NOT_READY = 0x80100010;
      public const uint E_INVALID_VALUE = 0x80100011;
      public const uint E_SYSTEM_CANCELLED = 0x80100012;
      public const uint F_COMM_ERROR = 0x80100013;
      public const uint F_UNKNOWN_ERROR = 0x80100014;
      public const uint E_INVALID_ATR = 0x80100015;
      public const uint E_NOT_TRANSACTED = 0x80100016;
      public const uint E_READER_UNAVAILABLE = 0x80100017;
      public const uint P_SHUTDOWN = 0x80100018;
      public const uint E_PCI_TOO_SMALL = 0x80100019;
      public const uint E_READER_UNSUPPORTED = 0x8010001A;
      public const uint E_DUPLICATE_READER = 0x8010001B;
      public const uint E_CARD_UNSUPPORTED = 0x8010001C;
      public const uint E_NO_SERVICE = 0x8010001D;
      public const uint E_SERVICE_STOPPED = 0x8010001E;
      public const uint E_UNEXPECTED = 0x8010001F;
      public const uint E_ICC_INSTALLATION = 0x80100020;
      public const uint E_ICC_CREATEORDER = 0x80100021;
      public const uint E_UNSUPPORTED_FEATURE = 0x80100022;
      public const uint E_DIR_NOT_FOUND = 0x80100023;
      public const uint E_FILE_NOT_FOUND = 0x80100024;
      public const uint E_NO_DIR = 0x80100025;
      public const uint E_NO_FILE = 0x80100026;
      public const uint E_NO_ACCESS = 0x80100027;
      public const uint E_WRITE_TOO_MANY = 0x80100028;
      public const uint E_BAD_SEEK = 0x80100029;
      public const uint E_INVALID_CHV = 0x8010002A;
      public const uint E_UNKNOWN_RES_MNG = 0x8010002B;
      public const uint E_NO_SUCH_CERTIFICATE = 0x8010002C;
      public const uint E_CERTIFICATE_UNAVAILABLE = 0x8010002D;
      public const uint E_NO_READERS_AVAILABLE = 0x8010002E;
      public const uint E_COMM_DATA_LOST = 0x8010002F;
      public const uint E_NO_KEY_CONTAINER = 0x80100030;
      public const uint W_UNSUPPORTED_CARD = 0x80100065;
      public const uint W_UNRESPONSIVE_CARD = 0x80100066;
      public const uint W_UNPOWERED_CARD = 0x80100067;
      public const uint W_RESET_CARD = 0x80100068;
      public const uint W_REMOVED_CARD = 0x80100069;
      public const uint W_SECURITY_VIOLATION = 0x8010006A;
      public const uint W_WRONG_CHV = 0x8010006B;
      public const uint W_CHV_BLOCKED = 0x8010006C;
      public const uint W_EOF = 0x8010006D;
      public const uint W_CANCELLED_BY_USER = 0x8010006E;
      public const uint W_CARD_NOT_AUTHENTICATED = 0x8010006F;
      #endregion

      #region Constructor

      public SmartCardReader()
      {

      }
      #endregion

      #region Metodos

      public long GetUID(ref byte[] UID)
      {
          long _result = 0;
          bool cardInserted = false;


          IntPtr _CardContext = IntPtr.Zero;
          IntPtr ActiveProtocol = IntPtr.Zero;

          // Establish Reader context:
          if (this._ReaderContext == IntPtr.Zero)
          {
              _result = SCardEstablishContext(2, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, out this._ReaderContext);

              #region Get List of Available Readers

              uint pcchReaders = 0;
              int nullindex = -1;
              char nullchar = (char)0;

              // First call with 3rd parameter set to null gets readers buffer length.
              _result = SCardListReaders(this._ReaderContext, null, null, ref pcchReaders);

              byte[] mszReaders = new byte[pcchReaders];

              // Fill readers buffer with second call.
              _result = SCardListReaders(this._ReaderContext, null, mszReaders, ref pcchReaders);

              // Populate List with readers.
              string currbuff = new ASCIIEncoding().GetString(mszReaders);
              int len = (int)pcchReaders;

              if (len > 0)
              {
                  while (currbuff[0] != nullchar)
                  {
                      nullindex = currbuff.IndexOf(nullchar);   // Get null end character.
                      string reader = currbuff.Substring(0, nullindex);
                      this._AvailableReaders.Add(reader);
                      len = len - (reader.Length + 1);
                      currbuff = currbuff.Substring(nullindex + 1, len);
                  }
              }

              #endregion

              // Select the first reader:
              this._ReaderName = this._AvailableReaders[0];
          }

          try
          {
              //Check if there is a Card in the reader:

              //dwShareMode: SCARD_SHARE_SHARED = 0x00000002 - This application will allow others to share the reader
              //dwPreferredProtocols: SCARD_PROTOCOL_T0 - Use the T=0 protocol (value = 0x00000001)

              if (this._ReaderContext != IntPtr.Zero)
              {
                  _result = SCardConnect(this._ReaderContext, this._ReaderName, 0x00000002, 0x00000001, ref _CardContext, ref ActiveProtocol);
                  if (_result == 0)
                  {
                      cardInserted = true;

                      SCARD_IO_REQUEST request = new SCARD_IO_REQUEST()
                      {
                          dwProtocol = (uint)ActiveProtocol,
                          cbPciLength = (uint)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SCARD_IO_REQUEST))
                      };

                      byte[] sendBytes = new byte[] { 0xFF, 0xCA, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 }; //<- get UID command for iClass cards
                      byte[] ret_Bytes = new byte[33];
                      uint sendLen = (uint)sendBytes.Length;
                      uint ret_Len = (uint)ret_Bytes.Length;

                      _result = SCardTransmit(_CardContext, ref request, ref sendBytes[0], sendLen, ref request, ret_Bytes, ref ret_Len);
                      if (_result == 0)
                      {
                          UID = ret_Bytes.Take(4).ToArray(); //only take the first 8, the last 2 bytes are not part of the UID of the card                                                           
                          string dataOut = byteToHexa(UID, UID.Length, true).Trim(); //Devolver la respuesta en Hexadecimal
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
          finally
          {
              SCardDisconnect(_CardContext, 0);
              SCardReleaseContext(this._ReaderContext);
          }
          return _result;
      }


      private string byteToHexa(byte[] byReadBuffer, int leng, bool bSpace)
      {
          string text2 = "";
          for (short num1 = 0; num1 < leng; num1 = (short)(num1 + 1))
          {
              short num2 = byReadBuffer[num1];

              text2 = text2 + System.Convert.ToString(num2, 16).PadLeft(2, '0');

              if (bSpace)
              {
                  text2 = text2 + " ";
              }
          }
          return text2.ToUpper();
      }


      //Get the address of Pci from "Winscard.dll".
      private IntPtr GetPciT0()
      {
          IntPtr handle = LoadLibrary("Winscard.dll");
          IntPtr pci = GetProcAddress(handle, "g_rgSCardT0Pci");
          FreeLibrary(handle);
          return pci;
      }

      #endregion


  }// Fin de la Clase
  }
  ```

PInvoke docs helped a lot:  https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/winscard.scardtransmit

Comment: in your code you write: UID = ret_Bytes.Take(4).ToArray(); //only take the first 8, the last 2 bytes are not part of the UID of the card. --> Now you do a take(4) but comment it as taking 8 bytes. Which one is now correct? 8 or 4? Because that's exactly where I currently struggle as there are MF1k cards out in the wild with either 4 byte or 8 byte UID and I need to handle both dynamically.

Comment: Yeah that's a typo, u only need 4 bytes, ur UID should look like this: FF.FF.FF.FF and not just for MF1k but for pretty much all of them. Upvote if u find my code usefull, thanks.

Comment: Actually that's not correct. You will need 4, 7 or 10 bytes according to NXP. Please see here (directly on the first page): https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN10927.pdf

Comment: Well, in the case of MF1k you only need the first 4 bytes, that is the answer to your question, my code does that.

Comment: THANK YOU !!!! This works perfectly and I don't understand why you don't have any upvote in 1 year !